# Simplification of exponential

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to understand why `FullSimplify` doesn't entirely simplify this expression

```
FullSimplify[E^(-2*t*g)*Sqrt[E^(4*t*(g + 2*I*l))], {l > 0, g > 0, t > 0}]
```

simplifies to

```
Sqrt[E^(4*(g + (2*I)*l)*t)]*E^(-2*g*t)
```

i.e. it doesn't eliminate the real part of the exponential, while

```
FullSimplify[ E^(-2*t*g)*Sqrt[E^(4*t*(g + 2*I*l))] == Sqrt[Exp[8 I l t]], {l > 0, g > 0, t > 0}]
```

yields `True`.

Comment: This does work `ComplexExpand[E^(-2*t*g)*Sqrt[E^(4*t*(g + 2*I*l))]] // 
 FullSimplify[#, {g > 0, t > 0, l > 0}] &`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ComplexExpand`

```
expr1 = E^(-2*t*g)*Sqrt[E^(4*t*(g + 2*I*l))];

expr2 = expr1 // ComplexExpand // 
  FullSimplify[#, {l > 0, g > 0, t > 0}] &
```

> Sqrt[E^(8*I*l*t)]

```
expr1 == expr2 // FullSimplify[#, {l > 0, g > 0, t > 0}] &
```

> True

Comment: +1. I had not seen your answer when I posted my comment.